# Simple Yet Compelling Macro Examples which are Not Already in Clojure

Tags: macros, clojure

I'm trying to write a macro tutorial, and now I need some examples which are simple to understand, and yet compelling.

The problem is that a lot of the obvious things are already in clojure and contrib. And I feel that "look, we can reimplement all the library functions" might not be the best argument for why macros are so great.

Has anyone got any cute (one-liners are best) examples that they wouldn't mind me using?

Here are the first three parts of the tutorial. It's a bit ropy at the moment, so any comments about how it could be made better would be gratefully received.

http://learnclojure.blogspot.com/2010/09/clojure-macro-tutorial-part-i-getting.html

http://learnclojure.blogspot.com/2010/09/clojure-macro-tutorial-part-ii-compiler.html

http://learnclojure.blogspot.com/2010/09/clojure-macro-tutorial-part-ii-syntax.html

Comment: Perhaps my favorite example, which I'm not sure is possible in clojure (maybe a limited subset with clj-cont, but completely in scheme), is implementing `yield`, like in python, via `call/cc`. It's a powerful example that really drives home the fact that macros can help you build even the wildest of constructs into the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would talk more about patterns: when and how is a macro used. eg...

- Protecting a resource. Examples: `binding`, `with-open`, ...

  ```
  (let [~x (get-resource)] (try ~@dostuff (finally (release-resource ~x))))
  ```
- Defining things. Examples: `defn`, `defsnippet` (enlive), `defservice` (ring)
- Macro/driver split. Especially this technique takes away a lot of macro pain.
  Like multiple evaluation or capture. Example: `with-bindings`
- Beautifying ugly code. eg. when [Taming multi-dim arrays](http://clj-me.cgrand.net/2009/10/15/multidim-arrays/)

Answer (score 6):

I'm working on some cryptography software in clojure. Its really fun and using unit testing makes it more fun because I don't get nervous about breaking things. The trouble is that all the crypto functions generate different results every time because they are driven by a fairly good IMHO psudo random number generator.

How do I test randomized functions?

with a bind macro of course!

```
(defmacro with-fake-prng [ & exprs ]
  "replaces the prng with one that produces consisten results"
  `(binding [com.cryptovide.split/get-prng (fn [] (cycle [1 2 3]))
             com.cryptovide.modmath/mody 719
             com.cryptovide.modmath/field-size 10]
       ~@exprs))
```

then I wrap my test functions in  `(with-fake-prng  (deftest mytest ....))`

clojure has a lot of these "bind macroes". like `with-out-string` and such.

I also have a macro that loads every namespace into the repl. (I dont use this much now that I have switched to cake)

```
(defmacro load-all []
  '(use 
   :reload-all
   'com.cryptovide.modmath
    ...  
   'com.cryptovide.gui
   'com.cryptovide.checksum
   'com.cryptovide.log))
```

ps: always mind the first rule of macro club

Comment: Great example! The alternative is to use a "dependency injection" framework, which is extremely ugly in so many cases.

Comment: As of Clojure 1.3, this won't work anymore, since `binding` can only redefine mappings for Vars declared dynamic (which your functions probably aren't).  Instead, we should now use the predefined macro `with-redefs`: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/with-redefs.  However, the larger point stands: this is a great example of the power of macros.  Just now it's already defined for us.

Comment: When I ported this code to 1.4 I declared get-prng, mody, and field-size to be dynamic.